# Installed Miniconda 4.2.11 and have import error while creating environment

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I am able to create environment from environment.yml file which has release number 4.2.7 but recently updated miniconda distribution on my Desktop to 4.2.11. Can I go back to my previous distribution?

Snippet of the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/ramya/miniconda2/bin/conda-env", line 4, in <module>
    import conda_env.cli.main
    File "/Users/ramya/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main.py", line 35, in <module>
    from . import main_attach
    File "/Users/ramya/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main_attach.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..env import from_environment
    File "/Users/ramya/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_env/env.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import yaml
    File "/Users/ramya/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_env/yaml.py", line 8, in <module>
    import yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here - I got hold of a previous download of Miniconda (Miniconda2-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh) Installation file and created my environment which resolved my problem.